# Nous tutoyons-nous sur French Language ?

Tags: discussion

Je viens de rejoindre la communauté French Language, et je me demandais si les membres se tutoyaient ou se vouvoyaient dans les questions/réponses.

En effet, c'est une question qui n'a pas lieu d'exister en anglais, car cette notion n'existe pas !

---

<sub>J'aurais plutôt tendance à tutoyer les gens, car je trouve cette forme plus chaleureuse et amicale, mais peut-être que cela peut gêner ou paraître irrespectueux ...</sub>